# AJAX request for jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function showDialog(link) {
    $('#dialog .newsletter-join').click(function() {
        email = $.trim($(this).parent().find('.email').val());
        if (email != "Email Address" && email.length > 5) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/newsletter/join',
                data: {
                    'email': email,
                    'pid': $('#dialog .pid').html().trim()
                }
            });

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

This code is executed correctly in FF and in chrome it runs perfect when executed in debugging mode, other wise it does not return anything.

When executed it shows alert box with nothing in it.  I don't see anything in the XMLHttp response in console as well.
I tried a few other changes:

```
cache:false // It just exeutes for the first time 
datatype:html
```

Could you please let me know how to track this issue?

Updated Code :

I am calling the Code using the following script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // $(window).load(function () {
    showDialog();
    return true;
    //});
});

function showDialog(link) {
    $('#dialog .newsletter-join').click(function() {
        email = $.trim($(this).parent().find('.email').val());
        if (email != "Email Address" && email.length > 5) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/newsletter/join',
                data: {
                    'email': email,
                    'pid': $('#dialog .pid').html().trim()
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("Suvvess" + data);
                },
                error: function(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("error" + errorThrown);
                }
            });

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

Latest Code change : 
I added the

```
  async: false
```

This change in ajax call is giving the expected result , but this would stop all scripts to    execute so still feel this cant be the permanent solution

Comment: Your `success:` line is outside the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo from my side .I was just looking to see if I get any xmlhttpresponse , even I take them out the code behavior is still the same

Comment: @KAPILPATIL : Can you post your updated code ?

Comment: @KAPILPATIL : You have removed success callback function?

Comment: @user1042031 : This is the original function that I am using before adding the on success call back , will add those functions back and paste it again

Comment: I updated the code with on success event

Answer (score 6):

You should close ajax function after error

```
$.ajax({
                url:'/newsletter/join',
                data:{ 'email':email, 'pid':$('#dialog .pid').html().trim() }

  >>>HERE REMOVE IT        });
```